# Определенное количество записей, либо не выбирать вообще. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Можно ли как-то выбрать определенное количество записей из таблицы, а в случае отсутствия нужного количества, не выбирать ничего?

Данный запрос делается в транзакции, и не хотелось бы, чтобы ненужные записи блокировались. Под ненужными, имеется ввиду записи, в недостаточном количестве.

Порядок действий выглядит вот так:

1) Стартуем транзакцию.

2) Проверяем, есть ли нужные записи в определенном количестве. Если да, обновляем их, и завершаем транзакцию.

3) Если нет, ищем другие записи по другим параметрам, и тоже в определенном количестве.

4) Повторяем пункты 2 и 3, пока не найдутся нужные записи (количество интераций ограничено).

5) Завершаем транзакцию.

В запросах это выглядело бы примерно так:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE param1 = value1 LIMIT 10 FOR UPDATE
```

Если запрос не дал результатов, делаем другой запрос, пока не получим нужный результат.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE param2 = value2 LIMIT 20 FOR UPDATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
with Q as(
  select * from table where param1 = value1 limit 10
)
select * from Q where (select count(1) from Q)=10 for update
```

Answer (score 0):

так не пойдет?

```
DECLARE
....
BEGIN
LOOP
IF EXISTS (
     SELECT count(*),0 x 
       FROM table WHERE param1 = value1 group by x  having  count(*)> 10
          ) THEN 
     делаем что надо
    END IF; 
если условие true выход
END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: Надо исключить ситуацию, когда уже сделал FOR UPDATE, а записей не хватает. В таком случае не желательно допускать блокировки транзакцией.